# How to know which extensions got updated in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have VS 2012 set to update automatically. How do I know which extensions got updated in Visual Studio 2012? Under updates in Extensions Manager, it says "No Items Found". Yet it needs to restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to Tools | Extensions and Updates - most have a date, version or link from which you can see what what happened.  The Updates would only have them if you did it manually and they were waiting to be updated.
[image]